# After Lasso: Store remaining variables as new dataframe (using R)

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, lasso-regression

First of all, thank you very much for your interest and time. My question (using R):
To predict the yvar, I have run a lasso regression which reduced the set of xvariables from 736 to 30.

```
lasso.mod =glmnet(x,y,alpha=1)
cv.out =cv.glmnet (x,y,alpha=1)
lasso.bestlam =cv.out$lambda.min
tmp_coef = coef(cv.out,s=lasso.bestlam)

varnames = data.frame(name = tmp_coef@Dimnames[[1]][tmp_coef@i])
mylist = list(name = tmp_coef@Dimnames[[1]][tmp_coef@i])
```

Hence, I have the remaining variable names as a data frame and also as a list.
How is it possible to create a new data frame which has these remaining 30 variables and their observations in it? In other words: How can I get a subset of my original data which does not contain 737 variables but only 31?

I think this should be quite easy, however I have been spending more than two hours and it never worked...

Best wishes,
Thomas

Comment: This seems to be a standard column selection problem. Take your old dataframe and select the columns in your list as a vector. E.g. `mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl")]` will select these two columns from the `mtcars` dataset.

Comment: Searching this site for help with column selection will provide several answers for you.

Comment: The problem is that the variables after lasso will maybe change (depending on some other things I will do before running the lasso). Therefore, I do not want to write every time 30 variables by hand. But thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot test your solution as I do not have the data, but this should do the trick:

```
varnames <- tmp_coef@Dimnames[[1]][tmp_coef@i]
as.data.frame(cbind(x[, varnames], y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `tmp_coef@Dimnames[[1]][tmp_coef@i]` variable contains the names of the remaining variables, but also contains "(Intercept)" as the first item. If you discard it with `-1]`, you can extract the columns:

```
x <- as.data.frame(x[, tmp_coef@Dimnames[[1]][tmp_coef@i][-1]])
```

Even simpler, you can use the indices in `tmp_coef@i` directly:

```
x <- as.data.frame(x[, tmp_coef@i[-1]])
```